# How to send the character "&" via HTTP POST to server with iOS 7?

Tags: ios, utf-8

I want to send some data via http post from my App to the server. All symbols can be accepted by the server, except the `&`.

1. the server is php;
2. content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and charset is utf-8.
3. Encoding is `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

I tried also changing the `&` with URLEncoding, i.e. `&` --> `%26`. the server can receive it, but cannot display it recht. It's shown in `%26`, not `&`.

But, the server can properly received and displayed, if it is sent by android or web side.

The code is the following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest  requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx.com/server.php"]];

postRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=&&&&"];   

postBody = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLConnection *postConnect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you

```
 NSString *encodedString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

It won't replace your string inline; it'll return a new string. That's implied by the fact that the method starts with the word "string". It's a convenience method to instantiate a new instance of NSString based on the current NSString.

Note--that new string will be autorelease'd, so don't call release on it when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be with the function

`(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)url, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"&", kCFStringEncodingUTF8))`